# How to get bluetooth RFCOMM to work consistently?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am trying to build an Android application that will interface with an external GPS receiver via the Bluetooth Serial Port Profile (SPP). I am using a Nexus One running 2.3.3. I have managed to get my application to receive data from GPS, but I have two issues: 1) When I connect to the device, it only works some of the time. Sometimes the connection just times out, other times it says the device is busy or in use. 2) I haven't been able to figure out how to send data back to the device, which is probably an issue of how I'm using the streams since the incoming stream is a blocking call.

I moved just the relevant code to a new Android application for testing, which is the following:

/res/layout/main.xml (two buttons and a textview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button android:id="@+id/btnStart" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Connect"></Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/btnSend" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Send Message"></Button>
<TextView android:id="@+id/textStatus" android:textSize="24sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Status Goes Here" />
</LinearLayout>
```

/src/com.example.bluetoothspp/MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.bluetoothspp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final String BTAG = "BTThread";
    static final int MSG_BT_GOT_DATA = 1;
    static final int MSG_BT_STATUS_MSG = 2;
    static final int MSG_BT_FINISHED = 99;

    Button btnStart, btnSend;
    TextView textStatus;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothDevice btdevice = null;
    Thread bThread;
    BluetoothSocket bsocket;
    InputStream bis = null; //Bluetooth input stream
    OutputStream bos = null; //Bluetooth output stream
    private String MACAddress = "00:01:95:06:1F:32";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        textStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(btnStartListener);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(btnSendListener);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }

    private OnClickListener btnStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(btnStart.getText().equals("Connect")){
                Log.i(TAG, "Connect button pressed");
                if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) { //No adapter. Fail
                    Log.e(TAG, "getDefaultAdapter returned null");
                    textStatus.setText("getDefaultAdapter returned null");

                } else {
                    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) { //Bluetooth disabled
                        Log.e(TAG, "Bluetooth is Disabled");
                        textStatus.setText("Bluetooth is Disabled");

                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Connecting to Device: " + MACAddress);
                        btdevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MACAddress);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Device: " + btdevice.getName());
                        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to Connect...");
                        textStatus.setText("Trying to Connect...");
                        Log.i(TAG, "Starting Thread");
                        try {
                            bThread = new Thread(new BluetoothClient(btdevice, true));
                            bThread.start();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create thread for bluetooth: " + e);
                            textStatus.setText("Could not create thread for bluetooth...");
                        }
                        btnStart.setText("Disconnect");
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnect button pressed");

                btnStart.setText("Connect");
            }
        }
    };
    private OnClickListener btnSendListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            textStatus.setText("Sending Message to Thread.");
            SendDataToBluetooth("something\r\n");
        }
    };


    public class BluetoothClient implements Runnable {
        public BluetoothClient(BluetoothDevice device, boolean IsAnHTCDevice) throws IOException {
            if (IsAnHTCDevice) {
                //This is a workaround for HTC devices, but it likes to throw an IOException "Connection timed out"
                try {
                    Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                    bsocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(1));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(BTAG, "Error at HTC/createRfcommSocket: " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(MSG_BT_STATUS_MSG, "MethodException: " + e));
                }
            } else {
                //This is the normal method, but on a Nexus One it almost always throws an IOException "Service discovery failed" message
                try {
                    UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
                    bsocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(BTAG, "Error at createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord: " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(MSG_BT_STATUS_MSG, "MethodException: " + e));
                }
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.i(BTAG, "Cancelling Discovery");
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                Log.i(BTAG, "Connecting to Socket");
                bsocket.connect();
                bis = bsocket.getInputStream();
                bos = bsocket.getOutputStream();
                Log.i(BTAG, "Socket created, streams assigned");
                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(MSG_BT_STATUS_MSG, "Device Connected"));
                Log.i(BTAG, "Waiting for data...");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int read = bis.read(buffer, 0, 4096); // This is blocking
                Log.i(BTAG, "Getting data...");
                while (read != -1) {
                    byte[] tempdata = new byte[read];
                    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, tempdata, 0, read);
                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(MSG_BT_GOT_DATA, tempdata));
                    read = bis.read(buffer, 0, 4096); // This is blocking
                }
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Log.i(BTAG, "Finished");
                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(MSG_BT_FINISHED));
            }
        }
    }
    public void SendDataToBluetooth(String cmd) { // You run this from the main thread.
        try {
            if (bsocket != null) {
                bos.write(cmd.getBytes());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SendDataToBluetooth", "Message send failed. Caught an exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    public Handler handler = new Handler() { // Handler for data coming from the network and bluetooth sockets
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_BT_GOT_DATA:
                Log.i("handleMessage", "MSG_BT_GOT_DATA: " + (String) msg.obj);
                textStatus.setText((String) msg.obj);
                break;
            case MSG_BT_STATUS_MSG:
                Log.i("handleMessage", "MSG_BT_STATUS_MSG: " + (String) msg.obj);
                textStatus.setText((String) msg.obj);
                break;
            case MSG_BT_FINISHED:
                Log.i("handleMessage", "MSG_BT_FINISHED");
                btnStart.setText("Connect");
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (bThread != null) { // If the thread is currently running, close the socket and interrupt it.
            Log.i(BTAG, "Killing BT Thread");
            try {
                bis.close();
                bos.close();
                bsocket.close();
                bsocket = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(BTAG, "IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(BTAG, "Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread moribund = bThread;
                bThread = null;
                moribund.interrupt();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            Log.i(BTAG, "BT Thread Killed");
        }
    }
}
```

I found that using the normal "bsocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);" method would usually result in a "Service discovery failed" message for me, so I also tried the "bsocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(1));" method. That works more often, but likes to time out when I try to connect.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Try listening to the incoming data and writing to the device in separate threads. This way you are separating blocking calls.
 Did you have a look at Bluetooth chat sample? The sample uses the similar threading technique.

Comment: That resolved the issue with writing data back to the socket. I still get the "Service discovery failed" and "Device or resource busy" messages some of the time when trying to connect. Any thoughts on that? It seems like it will connect fine several times in a row, then it throws one of these error messages for a while.

Comment: I found that the Bluetooth Android code will work consistently when connecting to a different device. The one I've been testing with only works some of the time. Strangely, a Bluetooth GPS app that I found in the market works great with that device, so there must be a different way of connecting that I haven't seen yet.

Comment: Try going through logs when it doesn't work. May be you are missing something or the device has some different implementation than other devices.

Comment: @Lance Lefebure - did you ever figure out the BT connection issues you described above?  I'm having the same issues with Android devices running OS < 2.3.5

Comment: @c12 - I think this is working fine because I haven't had any complaints about it. It's been a while since writing this and I can't recall what I did, but my app is open source, so feel free to have a look: http://lefebure.com/software/android-ntripclient/

Comment: @LanceLefebure - thanks for the source link.  Our socket connection logic is exact.  I'm having trouble mostly with a small percentage of Android phones.  Most notably the Motorola Droid X. I cant connect to the BT device if the droid x is already paired.  If I manually un-pair before connecting then it will connect.  Just get IOExceptions "connection refused" or "service discovery failed"..etc.  Ever run into anything like that?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: hey man can you help me..??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648942/send-text-message-from-one-device-to-another-via-bluetooth-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting 2.3 and up (which is currently installed [on over 50%](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) of android devices out there) you can use the [createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29) method to communicate with the device which will surely make it better and more connectable.

Comment: hey man can you help me..??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648942/send-text-message-from-one-device-to-another-via-bluetooth-in-android